# Using for instead of jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I want use a for loop instead of $.each. How is it?

My code with $.each is as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'get_units',
    data: { id : '1'},
    success: function (units) {
        $.each(units, function (index, val) { //I want change this line to for loop
            alert(index+'-'+val) // I want two result
        });
    },
    "error": function (x, y, z) {
        alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the your problem with using a `for` loop?

Comment: what's the problem with $.each function ?

Comment: @SKG an `$.each` adds a probably unnecessary complexity, as on the one hand a function call needs to be done for each iteration and on the other hand a new scope might be create. So it might be a comprehensible idea to change a `$.each` to a `for`

Comment: you can pass second parameter value as scope value in each function, to avoid creating scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), if you have objects:

```
var units = {
    'a': 'Hello',
    'b': 'World'
};

for (var prop in units) {
    console.log(prop);
    console.log(units[prop]);
}
```

If you have arrays, use [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
var units = ['Hello', 'World'];

for (var i = 0, l = units.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(units[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note: in a `for...in` loop i would not call it `index` but `key`, `prop`, or something similar. As `index` is something that is more common for the use with `Array` and indicates that is a numeric value in that range of `0 .. n`

Comment: @t.niese Nice, Done `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
    alert(i+'-'+units[i]);
}
```